# "Can you not do that?"

Tags: grammaticality

I've been told that the expression "Can you not" (*Can/Could + subject + not + verb*) is used in casual conversation but it's not grammatically correct. Is this the case?

I'm aware that it wouldn't be appropriate in a formal / written context. I've also heard that it's only correct when an interjection is between the subject and the verb (i.e. "Can you please not do that?" or "Can you, like, not do that?").

Also, would the use of "Could" make the expression appropriate for a polite request?

Comment: It's grammatical, it's called verb-phrase ellipsis ([VPE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis)). I made a post about this in my [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1057144?noredirect=1) - skip towards the end. VPE is normal in every-day English. However it requires an established context, in order to be understood by a third-party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be more polite to say/ask: *Would* you not do that? Or *Will* you not do that? Could and can seem impolite, because they suggest that the other person might be incapable of doing something.

> ...[would](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Usage/faq0002.html) is more polite, because it expresses the idea of probability, and of willingness, and of the desire that something be done, whereas “could” is more in the realm of ability (yes I can).

Comment: That makes sense. Is the use of Can/Could grammatically correct as well?

Comment: @Nico de Ory ~ I don't see any real problem with the *grammar*, technically speaking. Some people may take issue with the wording because they instinctively view it as being vaguely impolite (even if unintentional), and without understanding the precise nature of the problem, they sometimes criticize the grammar instead.